# Having an error while creating artifact and executing jar files in intellij idea for Java project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project, artifact

After I finished creating my Java project in Intellij Idea, I have created an artifact for that project and open it in explorer.

But when I open it in explorer, the application shown up is different from the project I run in Intellij Idea when I hit the 'run; button...

Can you guys help me out?

[This is the picture showing that I have created an artifact.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjxJF.png)

[The second picture shows the output of my project after hitting the run button. That's alright.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDsL0.png)

[But when I click on the artifact and open it in explorer in my computer storage, it shows blank output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cEVP.png)

[is this the dos prompt you want?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO1Zx.png)

Comment: Hello, first of all do you have any kind of error if you run it from a dos console?

Comment: no error when I hit the run button in intelli idea

Comment: I know that, you already wrote it. What is shown when running your jar in a dos console using java -jar or any other command you may use to start your app using the generated artifact?

Comment: You can click on my third statement that will show picture that is the output when running the jar. file which is showing an incomplete file

Comment: Pictures are pictures, logs are logs. Please open a dos prompt, run your jar using java -jar and share with us if any message/exception is shown.

Comment: where to find the dos prompt in intellij idea?

Comment: I have added dos prompt in picture 4 above

Comment: Ok, i'm sorry.I understand now that you're new to java programming so i will be more explicit. When executing a runnable jar by double click it is the same than executing: java -jar "Snake Game App.jar" in a dos prompt. Why am i requesting this? because the dos prompt will receive the output of the execution (exceptions, errors, info) which will be a good starting point to diagnose your problem

Comment: FYI: yes what you shown as picture 4 is a dos prompt, now you only need to execute in the dos prompt : java -jar "Snake Game App.jar"